# Adding some space between tables with css

Tags: css

I have generated a HTML page with several tables.
Right now they show one after another without any space between them

my current css file is very simple

```
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    /*width: 100%;*/
  }  
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }

tr:nth-child(even) {  
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }
```

How can I add some spacing between the tables using only css?

I tried

```
table{
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

but it did not work out

I modified it to

```
margin-bottom:10px;
    float:bottom;
```

and it seems to work.

Comment: Please edit your question and use the stack snippet button to create a [mcve] demonstrating your issue as with the code you have currently provided, you shouldn't have an issue

Comment: `float:bottom` is not a thing. And what supposedly isn't working with a `margin-bottom`, is currently unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. Check this snippet:

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
  }
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }

tr:nth-child(even) {  
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>aaaaa</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td>bbbb</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td>aabbbbaaa</td></tr>
</table>
```

If you have `width: 100%;` you need to add `margin-top:10px` for example.

Comment: Ah, well the tables are horizontally aligned, but what if I just want them one after another vertically?

Comment: As I said in the answer, you need to add margin-top:10px.